# angular js peity is not working with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

for creating a simple pie chart i am using [piety](http://benpickles.github.io/peity/). that is very much simple . and its working fine with js.

html

```
<span class='pie' data-peity='{ "fill": ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7", "#ffffff"]}'>0.52/1.561</span>
```

and required js--

```
$(".pie").peity("pie");
```

thats it .. works very fine but problem is within angular js ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat='item in data'>
     <span class='pie' data-peity='{ "fill": ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7", "#ffffff"]}'>{{item.start}}/{{item.end}}</span>
</div>
```

but that is not working.

so i thik that may be i need a directive..so i made it..

```
app.directive('pieChart', function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
        $timeout(function () {
            element.peity("pie")
        }, 100);
    }
};
});
```

and html===>

```
<td><span data-peity='{ "fill": ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7", "#ffffff"]}' pieChart>0.52/1.561</span></td>
without ng-repeat
```

but that is also not working for me . i dont know why.can anybody help me...

Comment: Can you try with `pie-chart` instead of `pieChart` for the attribute name ?

Comment: @nayan Uh, it works great! can you please check [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63ec49xv/)

Comment: thanks @eroak .. you r right. i misspell the directive name...

Comment: @NarenMurali  Also i need a small help ... from where i can learn how to write directive for angular...

Comment: Check my answer for more explanation. I hope it will be helpful for others

Comment: @nayan If you wrote this directive on  your own, GOOD JOB, secondly there is no definitive guide I have apart from the content on the internet, sorry, refer here [jQuery Plugins as Angular Directives](http://bencentra.com/code/2015/09/29/jquery-plugins-angular-directives.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a directive, the name you specify is in lower camel-case `pieChart`. When you use it with as an attribute, it must be in `kebab-case`, like `pie-chart`

> AngularJS normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically **refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase** normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, **since HTML is case-insensitive**, we refer to directives **in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited** attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)

[The JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63ec49xv/) from Naren Murali